# Can I store the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename into a variable?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I store the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` into a variable?

If possible, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Although the return value looks like a standard data set, the SQL parser **won't allow it** in such standard queries as this:

```sql
SELECT `Create Table` INTO @foo FROM (SHOW CREATE TABLE bar);
-- results in ERROR 1064 near 'SHOW CREATE TABLE bar'
```

You can query the `information_schema` database to get the information you want though. This will provide similar output:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
    'CREATE TABLE `',
    t.TABLE_NAME,
    '`(\n',
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
            '  `',
            c.COLUMN_NAME,
            '` ',
            c.COLUMN_TYPE,
            ' ',
            IF(c.DATA_TYPE = 'varchar', CONCAT('COLLATE ', c.COLLATION_NAME, ' '), ''),
            IF(c.IS_NULLABLE = 'NO', 'NOT NULL', ''),
            IFNULL(CONCAT(' DEFAULT ', c.COLUMN_DEFAULT), ''),
            ' ',
            c.EXTRA
        )
        SEPARATOR ',\n'
    ),
    '\n) ENGINE=',
    t.ENGINE,
    ' AUTO_INCREMENT=',
    t.AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ' DEFAULT CHARSET=',
    s.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME,
    ' COLLATE=',
    t.TABLE_COLLATION
) AS create_statement
FROM information_schema.schemata s
INNER JOIN information_schema.tables t
    ON s.SCHEMA_NAME = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
INNER JOIN information_schema.columns c
    ON (c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA AND c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME)
WHERE s.SCHEMA_NAME = 'mydatabase' AND t.TABLE_NAME = 'mytable';
```

The notable exception being key information.

Comment: Thank you for your input. the code is not workingI get a syntax error. Here is what I tried `SELECT `Create Table` FROM (SHOW CREATE TABLE guardi.accounts) AS s;
`

Comment: That's why the answer said it won't allow it!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the results, with php for example:

```
function getCreateSQLFromTableName($table){
    $sql = "SHOW CREATE TABLE $table";
    echo $sql;
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if($res){
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
        $createSQL = $row['Create Table'];
        return $createSQL;
    }
    else{
        echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error(). "\n";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 *
 * Get info about table from 'SHOW CREATE TABLE'
 *
 * @param string $table table
 * @return false|array
 */
function table_info($table, $include_fields = ['table', 'alter'])
{
    if ( strlen($table) > 0 )
    {
        $query = "SHOW CREATE TABLE {$table}";
        $result = mqc($query);
        if ( $result )
        {
            $fields_separator_begin = ' (' . n();
            $fields_separator_end = n() . ') ';
            $fields_separator_item = ',' . n();
            $alter_separator = ' ';
            $info_data = mfa($result);
            $response['table'] = trim($info_data['Table']);
            $response['create'] = trim($info_data['Create Table']);
            
            $info_data_2 = explode($fields_separator_begin, $info_data['Create Table'], 2);
            $info_data_3 = explode($fields_separator_end, $info_data_2[1]); unset($info_data_2);
            $fields_string = trim($info_data_3[0]);
            $fields_data = explode($fields_separator_item, $fields_string);
            $alter_string = trim($info_data_3[1]);
            $alter_data = explode($alter_separator, $alter_string, 5);
            unset($info_data_3);
            
            $primary = trim(end($fields_data));
            $response['primary'] = $primary;
            $response['alter'] = [];
            foreach ($alter_data as $alter_datum)
            {
                if ( ifound($alter_datum, '=') )
                {
                    $alter_item_data = explode('=', $alter_datum);
                    $response['alter'][$alter_item_data[0]] = $alter_item_data[1];
                } else
                {
                    $response['alter'][$alter_datum] = $alter_datum;
                }
            }
            end($fields_data);
            $key = key($fields_data);
            unset($fields_data[$key]);
            $response['fields'] = [];
            foreach ($fields_data as $field)
            {
                $field_data = explode(' ', trim($field), 3);
                $response['fields'][] = $field_data;
            }
            
            if ( count($include_fields) > 0 )
            {
                $response_slice = [];
                foreach ($response as $response_field => $response_data)
                {
                    if ( in_array($response_field, $include_fields) )
                    {
                        $response_slice[$response_field] = $response_data;
                    }
                }
                return $response_slice;
            } else return $response;
        } else return false;
    } else return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
$table_info = table_info('table_name', [])

print_r($table_info);

Array
(
    [table] => caop_access
    [create] => CREATE TABLE `caop_access` (
  `access_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `access_title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `access_level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `access_desc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`access_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Type of access'
    [primary] => PRIMARY KEY (`access_id`)
    [alter] => Array
        (
            [ENGINE] => MyISAM
            [AUTO_INCREMENT] => 7
            [DEFAULT] => DEFAULT
            [CHARSET] => utf8
            [COMMENT] => 'Type of access'
        )

    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => `access_id`
                    [1] => int(11)
                    [2] => NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => `access_title`
                    [1] => varchar(50)
                    [2] => NOT NULL
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => `access_level`
                    [1] => int(11)
                    [2] => NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => `access_desc`
                    [1] => varchar(100)
                    [2] => NOT NULL
                )

        )

)
```

Works for me...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).